# Passing powershell variable to robocopy

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-2.0, robocopy

I have a robocopy job to copy files from one folder to another location.

```
"D:\inetpub\www.test.com.au\App_Data\Indexes" "D:\inetpub\www.test2.com.au\livewww\App_Data\Examine" /MIR /IS /MON:1 /MOT:5
```

This is working fine but we have started using Octopus deployment and the web root folder ,i.e `D:\inetpub\www.test2.com.au\livewww\App_Data\Examine` is not the same and keeps changing after every deploy like

```
D:\Octopus\Dev\Presentation.Web\2017.9.320-ap\App_Data\Examine
D:\Octopus\Dev\Presentation.Web\2017.9.321-ap\App_Data\Examine
D:\Octopus\Dev\Presentation.Web\2017.9.322-ap\App_Data\Examine
```

I am thinking to use powershell to get the current root of the website `www.test2.com.au` and pass this location to robocopy.

I am new to powershell and have never worked in powershell so my question is that is it possible to use powershell and robocopy together like getting the current root of the website `www.test2.com.au` and pass that to robocopy to execute the command. How this is possible? Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: this seems to work for me on 2nd half of your question.  assign variable `$pyoi_prcsmsg = "D:\home\work\fb440.dumper\ps_list_prcsmsg.py"`.  then execute command `&"python" "$pyoi_prcsmsg"`.  So .... `& "robocopy" "D:\inetpub\www.test.com.au\App_Data\Indexes" "$rootvar"` perhaps?

Comment: To clarify, you're just going to use the folder name to determine the target? Or are you going to query IIS for the physical file path? I use Visual Studio Team Services, and one of the things is they perform string replacement on scripts before execution, which changes how you manage escaping string data.

Comment: i will query IIS for the physical path

Comment: Basically i am looking for a powershell script to query the IIS for the physical path and then pass it to the robocopy. Is it possible to write a script like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you are looking to do is possible. The Web Server Administration module for Windows PowerShell includes the Internet Information Services (IIS) cmdlets that let you manage the configuration and run-time data of IIS.

```
import-module WebAdministration
$physicalPath = Get-WebSite "Default Web Site" | % PhysicalPath
```

OR, if it is a web application

```
$physicalPath = Get-WebApplication "Web.Application" -Site "Default Web Site" | % PhysicalPath
```

Now you can use the `$physicalPath` variable when invoking an external exe such as RoboCopy.